Identify the truth teller, the liar and the spy
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

In a room there are three people, a truth
teller, a liar and a spy.
The truth teller is always honest.  The liar
always lies.  The spy sometimes lies and sometimes
tells the truth.
You ask each one who they are:

The  first person says, "I am not the truth teller."
The second person says, "I am not the liar."
The  third person says, "I am not the spy."

But which person is really the truth teller? And
which one is the liar and which one is the spy?


 First person must be the spy since the truth teller could not say that (it would be lying, and they can't do that) and the liar would not say that (since it would be true).


 Third person can't be the liar since it would also be truthful to say "I am not the spy". So they must be a truth teller.


 That leaves only the liar as the second person.

